# What is the best practise for REST URLs in querying is reserved or is exist

Tags: rest, api

I have API for booking system.
Two basic entities:- Booking and Property

```
public class Booking
{
    public DateTime CheckInDate {get; set;}
    public DateTime CheckOutDate {get; set;}
    public int PropertyId {get; set;}
}

public class Property
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
}
```

I need to know if a specific property available in a period or not.

Is this URL valid for this request?

> /api/booking/availableProperty?PropertyId=1&CheckInDate=1/1/2017&CheckOutDate=1/2/2017

Is it valid to return a boolean as result of isPropertyReserved URL?

> /api/booking/isPropertyReserved?PropertyId=1&CheckInDate=1/1/2017&CheckOutDate=1/2/2017

Answer (score 0):

In REST, instead of trying to define numerous discoordinated API end-points for each single case you should concentrate on defining the [*collections* and *resources*](https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/rest-api-design-resource-modeling).

In your model, *Property* represents a resource which has an *identifier* and can be *booked* from `check-in` till `check-out` date, so it seems natural to introduce the `properties` collection (but, depending on your requirements you may choose to introduce `bookings` collection):

**Request** (get all Properties)

```
GET: api/properties
```

**Response**

```
[
  {
    "url": "api/properties/1",
    "bookings":[
      {
        "url": "api/properties/1/bookings",
        "checkInDate": "2017-01-01",
        "checkOutDate": "2017-02-01"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "url": "api/properties/2",
    "bookings": []
  }
]
```

**Request** (get Property with id 1)

```
GET: api/properties/1
```

**Response**

```
{
  "url": "api/properties/1",
  "bookings":[
    {
      "url": "api/properties/1/bookings",
      "checkInDate": "2017-01-01",
      "checkOutDate": "2017-02-01"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Request** (get all the bookings for Property with id 1)

```
GET: api/properties/1/bookings
```

**Response**

```
[
  {
    "url": "api/properties/1/bookings",
    "checkInDate": "2017-01-01",
    "checkOutDate": "2017-02-01"
  }
]
```

**Request** (check if there is any booking for the specific date)

```
GET: api/properties/1/bookings/2017-01-15
```

**Response** (a booking details, if found; empty result if not)

```
{
  "url": "api/properties/1/bookings/2017-01-15",
  "checkInDate": "2017-01-01",
  "checkOutDate": "2017-02-01"
}
```

Comment: For modularity purposes we currently don't want the property to depend on booking but switching positions is acceptable; the booking can depend on property.

May be we should rethink about the relation between the property and booking.

Comment: Sure, I do not know the entire domain. Of course you should take your business rules into account when designing _resources_. My intention was to show that instead of _procedural_ call `isPropertyReserved` you may design a resource answering the same question in a rest style. E.g. `api\bookings\1` may return booking dates for Property 1. `api\bookings\2017-02-03\2017-03-03` may return all Properties available for booking in this date range. Finaly, `api\bookings\2017-02-03\2017-03-03\1` may return the booking status (e.g. 'booked' or 'available').

Comment: Is it good practice to return properties although the api URL refers to bookings "api\bookings\2017-02-03\2017-03-03"?. I think this may leads to confusion.